# Call objects based on one class with the different attributes

Tags: r, oop

Is it possible to call objects with different attributes based on one class?
For example here i want to have `zlab` attribute for one object and not for another one.
I tried to use `do.call` with `structure`, but it doesn't work, as I thought. Or maybe it should be constructed in some other way?

```
chart <- function(domain, n, f, col, zlab, ...) {
      x <- y <- seq(min(domain), max(domain), length.out = n)
      fun <- function(x, y) {}
      body(fun) <- substitute(f)
        do.call(
        lapply, structure(list(x = x, y = y, f = fun, 
                               col=col, zlab = zlab, ...), ...),
                class = "myChart")
    }

# plot method
plot.myChart <- function(x, ...) {
  z = outer(x$x, x$y, x$f)
  persp(x$x, x$y, z, col = x$col, zlab = x$zlab, ...)
}

# object call
chr1 <- chart(c(-6, 6), 
             n = 30, 
             sqrt(x^2 + y^2),
             col = 'blue',
             zlab = "Height")

chr2 <- chart(c(-5, 5), 
             n = 30, 
             x^2 + y^2,
             col = 'green')
plot(chr1)
plot(chr2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add defaults for each argument, so that if any are skipped, they have a sensible fallback. This is a bit harder with `f`, but can be done inside the function using a combination of `missing`, `match.call` and `quote`:

```r
chart <- function(domain = c(-1, 1), n = 10, f, col = 'gray90', zlab = '', ...) 
{
      x <- y <- seq(min(domain), max(domain), length.out = n)
      f <- if(missing(f)) quote(x + y) else match.call()$f
      
      structure(list(x = x, y = y, f = as.function(c(alist(x=, y=), f)), 
                     col = col, zlab = zlab, ...),
                class = "myChart")
}

# plot method
plot.myChart <- function(x, ...) {
  z = outer(x$x, x$y, x$f)
  persp(x$x, x$y, z, col = x$col, zlab = x$zlab, ...)
}

# object call
chr1 <- chart(c(-6, 6), 
             n = 30, 
             sqrt(x^2 + y^2),
             col = 'blue',
             zlab = "Height")

chr2 <- chart(c(-5, 5), 
             n = 30, 
             x^2 + y^2,
             col = 'green')

plot(chr1)
```

[image]

```r
plot(chr2)
```

[image]

Note we even get a result with no arguments passed to `chart` at all.

```r
chr3 <- chart()
plot(chr3)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this helps

```
chart <- function(domain, n, f, col, zlab, ...) {
      x <- y <- seq(min(domain), max(domain), length.out = n)
      fun <- function(x, y) {}
      body(fun) <- substitute(f)
      structure(c(list(x = x, y = y, f = fun, col=col, zlab = zlab), 
          c(...)), class = "myChart")
       
    }
```

-testing

```
chr1 <- chart(c(-6, 6), 
             n = 30, 
             sqrt(x^2 + y^2),
             col = 'blue',
             zlab = "Height")
             
chr2 <- chart(c(-5, 5), 
                          n = 30, 
                          x^2 + y^2,
                          zlab = NULL,
                          col = 'green')
plot(chr1)
plot(chr2)
```

Comment: Thank you! But is it possible to completely skip `zlab` in the second object call without setting it to null?

Comment: @Aella You can grab the element in `plot` function to check `if(missing(x$zlab)) x$zlab <- NULL`

Comment: I meant in `chart` function because you have an argument already defined.  Or you may have a default argument as `zlab = NULL` in `chart`

Comment: and if it's not `zlab`, but `col`? when i set it to null, object is called without a color, even if there is such an attribute in the call

Comment: @Aella Are you setting it as `NULL` in `chart`